# How to add Object in Iframe with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, iframe

> I want to add this object in **iframe** . how can i do it ?

```
 <object classid="hhggg11211" width="760" height="540"
                    id="TvGame" align="middle">
                    <param name="movie" value="Flash/TvGame.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#a9a7b3" />
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery or some other framework? Can you even use a JavaScript solution? Are you trying to dynamically generate and add the `object` tag in the iframe or is it as simple as @Terry said?

Answer (score 1):

you need to put that code into a html file, then put the url of the html into the src attribute of the iframe tag, should be very easy to do!

1. make a file called filename.html
2. copy the contents above into it
3. open the page that you want to put the iframe into
4. change the src attribute to point to the file made in step 1

Comment: `should be very easy to do` is not an answer! Please read the FAQ and make sure you write a proper answer, or simply comment and do not answer!